# Ajax call from Greasemonkey to a Servlet: response failure

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets, greasemonkey

Though I've programming experience, am completely new to GS, JS, or anything related to UI.

Scenario: Making an AJAX call from Greasemonkey script to a Servlet

Greasemonkey/JS Code:

```
function getResultsData(query){
alert("Getting the Data");
$.ajax( 
    {
    cache: false,   
    data: {"q":query},      
    dataType:"text",
    url: "http://myserver.com:8000/search?",
    success: processData        
    }); //end of $.ajax }

function processData(data){
alert("Got the data");
var myResultDiv = document.getElementById("searchRes");
myResultDiv.innerHTML = data; }
```

Servlet Code:

```
        System.out.println("-----------This is an AJAX call------------------");
        //Commented the original logic
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        resp.getWriter().write("Text from Servlet");
```

Problem:

- GS/JS code works perfectly if the url (in $.ajax) is some other existing API. Response reflects in the UI
- However, when I give my server's url, I can observe in the Firebug.Console that there's no http response for that call but the status says 200 OK with the whole entry turned 'RED'.
- When I test the url copied from Firebug's 'http call entry', it's working perfectly as I can see the response 'Text from Servlet' on the new tab.

Can someone please help.

**NOTE** Website on which greasemonkey runs, and my server belong to same domain, i.e.

Greasemonkey website: wwww.example.com

My server: www.myserver.example.com

Comment: can you change the url to "search" instead of "http://myserver.com:8080/search?" .... also add another line in your servlet ... resp.getWriter().flush()

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried both, no luck.
I assume, you meant - "http://myserver.com:8080/search"

Comment: skip the myserver.com:8080 part ... just give the relative URL

Comment: myserver & the website on which greasemonkey is enabled are different from each other.

Comment: You normally cannot make ajax calls to another server. This is blocked to prevent cross-site scripting attacks. I'm not sure how you would communicate with another server in a greasemonkey script though considering you can't place any server side code on the pages a user visits...

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Anyways, I write the server and I do not block any external reqs. I assume that you meant servers block external ajax reqs?

Comment: @mattedgod Updated 'NOTE' section in the question according to your point.

Comment: @Firefox No the browsers block the requests. If it's javascript it's all happening on the client-side remember. Also, I'm not 100% sure but I think as far as the browser is concerned `myserver.example.com` and `example.com` are different servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @mattedgod. His comment triggered me to research more and I found the answer.

Add the following snippet to make it work.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

Surprisingly, it doesn't work if I explicitly specify my own server's full http address in the header. I yet to find out why.